# how get element from List based on its name?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark

I have a path that contains subpath ,each subpath contains files

```
      path="/data"
```

I implemented tow function to get csv files from each sub path

```
      def getListOfSubDirectories(directoryName: String): Array[String] = {
  (new File(directoryName))
    .listFiles
    .filter(_.isDirectory)
    .map(_.getName)
}
      def getListOfFiles(dir: String, extensions: List[String]): List[File] = {
  val d = new File(dir)
  d.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList.filter { file =>
    extensions.exists(file.getName.endsWith(_))
  }
}
```

each sub path contain 5 csv files : contextfile.csv,datafile.csv,datesfiles.csv,errors.csv,testfiles so my problem that i'll work with each file in a separate dataframe how I can get name of file for the right dataframe for example I want to get the name of files that concern context (i.e contextfile.csv). I worked like this but for each iteration the logic and the ranking in th List change

```
  val dir=getListOfSubDirectories(path)
  for (sup_path <- dir)
   { val Files = getListOfFiles(path + "//" + sup_path, List(".csv"))
  val filename_context = Files(1).toString
  val filename_datavalue = Files(0).toString
  val filename_error = Files(3).toString
  val filename_testresult = Files(4).toString
```

}

any help and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it just a simple filter

```
  val filename_context = Files.filter(f =>f.getName.contains("context")).last.toString
  val filename_datavalue = Files.filter(f =>f.getName.contains("data")).last.toString
  val filename_error = Files.filter(f =>f.getName.contains("error")).last.toString
  val filename_testresult = Files.filter(f =>f.getName.contains("test")).last.toString
```